# Not receiving the same amount of bytes that i'm sending - c# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

i have this weird problem with my project:

im using sockets, and the server/client code is the same, they both use 2 different threads (one that send and one that receive) but the data that im getting is not what im sending.

sending:

```
double[] data = new double[3];

// i'm sending this double array, in the actual code it's filled with 3 numbers

byte[] result = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(double)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, result, 0, result.Length);

// converting to byte

clientSocket.Send(result);

// at this point, the array size is 24 bytes (the size doesnt change for every time i'm trying to send) and i'm sending it to the client/server.
```

receiving:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(clientSocket.Receive(b, SocketFlags.None));
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(bytes);

// receiving the data, buffer size is 1024

double[] values = new double[bytes.Length / 8];
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
     values[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, i * 8);

// converting back to double[]

this.receivingData = values;

// bytes is an array with only 4 bytes and receivingData is a double array filled with nothing. (this happens every time im receiving data and the bytes values is allways the same)
```

At first i thought that there is something wrong in the conversion to double[], so i tried different ways, but they all give the same outcome.

What am i missing?

Comment: `Socket.Receive` copies the received bytes to the byte array that is passed to it as a parameter. You're getting the bytes of the integer returned by the method, which is the number of bytes received. You're supposed to use `b` instead of `bytes` here.

Comment: You probably should replace all of this, including the broken array reversal, with BinaryReader/Writer. It handles partial reads (which you do not)and endianness. You are working at too low of an abstraction level. You want to send doubles, not mess with bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Receive returns number of received bytes. You need to properly handle if it receives fewer bytes then it was told, e.g. loop till you receive necessary number of bytes. Here is [sample](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html) how you would do that in case of streams, you can try similar approach.

Also in such cases you need to ensure numbers are sent/received in same eindianness, which I hope you have done.

PS. As it was mentioned in the comments, it seems you are not correctly using `Receive` either.

Comment: In the actual it was on an endless loop with much more details, i just wanted to show you my idea. you are right , i've changed the buffer size to 24 and built the received double array from it, and not from the method **Receive** output. amateur mistake..